# Tag differentiation regarding [plink]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

### Problem

So it turns out there are two major tools both sharing the name [plink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plink).

One is what the current tag is meant to be for, a [command-line interface to the PuTTY back ends](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter7.html).

The other is a [whole genome association analysis toolset](https://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/index.shtml).

### Current Usage

I don't have numbers to back this up, but I believe that the PuTTY-associated plink is more commonly used on this site, especially because both https://www.biostars.org/ and [bioinformatics SE](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour) take some questions that might be on-topic for the bio version. Bioinformatics-SE's [version of this tag](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plink) doesn't have any description and is named the same. However, I believe both versions are on-topic for Stack Overflow, especially since the programmatic usage and manipulation of data using the bio version of the tool can be nontrivial.

Here are some examples of the current tag being misused:

- [I would like to read plink files using pandas-plink in GC Datalab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54658591/1456253)
- [How do I split my bed bim and fam files by family ID in plink?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18919830/1456253)
- [Convert plink .ped separate nucleotides format to slash genotypes format using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49075172/1456253)
- [How to replace a column in .fam with .txt in unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68020045/how-to-replace-a-column-in-fam-with-txt-in-unix)

There are even some questions specifically running into this naming collision as a problem:

- [Plink error "Stopping as there are no SNPs left for analysis"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49234633/1456253)

### Suggestions

So normally I'd just make the bio version of the tag, *but I'm not sure what a good name would be*. As far as I know, plink (bio version) doesn't stand for anything (I'd be happy if someone would correct me on that), and isn't associated with another tool, or even organization like plink is with PuTTY.

Here are some absolutely lukewarm level suggestions:

- [plink-gwas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plink-gwas) (gwas is a term in bioinformatics for genome-wide
  association studies)
- [plink-toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plink-toolset)
- [plink-genomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plink-genomics) (or is it genetics? Bio people, please have mercy)
- [plink-bioinformatics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plink-bioinformatics)

Comment: Should [[tag:plink]] also be renamed? We all know that many users are incapable of reading (the tag's excerpt) so changing it's name will hopefully at least stop *some* of the users when they notice that the tag they are actually using isn't what they wanted. (Though, again, even that doesn't always help... >_< )

Comment: I've created the [plink-genomics] tag and added ([suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33173413)) the beginnings of a tag wiki. Since I'm still below 2k rep, I won't retag things en masse unless the questions also have other editable concerns.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A quick glance suggests that the *vast* majority are the PuTTY tool.

I'd suggest retagging all the ones about the genome association analysis toolset to something else and renaming the tag to [putty-plink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/putty-plink). With a synonym, probably, given that it's the vast majority of the usage.

I like [plink-genomics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/plink-genomics) for the genome association analysis toolset, because it's both specific and immediately obvious that it's not the PuTTY tool.

Comment: If anyone who does this sort of work can confirm whether "genomics" is an accurate description, that would be fantastic.

Comment: This looks like a good answer. I'll wait a couple of hours to accept in case anyone wants to chime in.

Comment: @RyanM `plink-genomics` sounds fine to me.

Comment: Is there any point in having this tag for SO? Sure, parsing the output of `plink-genomics` can be hard, but that's just a text processing task. So you can tag with a general `text-processing` and perhaps also a general `bioinformatics` tag, so you can just delete the `plink-genomics` tag and be done with it. Is that not simpler and more appropriate for SO?

Comment: @terdon. You should add this as an answer. IMO I believe its bad practice to parse the plink outputs manually. You absolutely can do it, but many times the files come in groups which all reference each other. General guidance I've seen is to only modify things with the tool.

Another reason to not just use sed or awk or whatever, is that efficient production use of plink will commonly use binary only files to cut down on file size (these things can be 100+ GB of plain text).

Comment: @code11 these all sound like even better reasons why such questions would be off topic here.